# Certain text on screen is being pushed around when window is resized/minimized

Tags: html, css, text, screen-size

I am extremely new to HTML/CSS and have been messing with it exclusively for about 2 weeks now. Attempting to make a website and was doing fairly well for my layout until I noticed that upon resizing the window, some of the text is being pushed around far to much.

Everything else stays put fairly well, the text inside the <"p"> tags are not however.

Any help is appreciated and criticism is welcome!

Here is the **HTML**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<header>

 <title>CakesbyKay</title>
 <link href="cakes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</header>

<body>
 <span class="topheader"> 
 <img src="Pictures/awningheader.png" class="awningtop">
 <img src="Pictures/Logo.png" class="logotop">
 <img src="Pictures/mainboxmid.png" class="mainboxmid">
 </span>
<div class="bgbreak">
</div>

<div class="headernav">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="Cakes.html">Cakes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div class="polaroid">
  <p class="weddingcaketext">Wedding Cakes</p>
  <img src="Pictures/weddingcakethumbnail.jpg" class="weddingthumbnail">
  <p class="babyshowertext">Babyshower Cakes</p>
  <img src="Pictures/babyshowercakethumbnail.jpg" class="babyshowerthumbnail">
  <p class="birthdaycaketext">Birthday Cakes</p>
   <img src="Pictures/birthdaycakethumbnail.jpg" class="birthdaycakethumbnail">
     <p class="holidaycaketext">Holiday Cakes</p>
   <img src="Pictures/holidaycakethumbnail.jpg" class="holidaycakethumbnail">
</div>
 
</div>
```

Here is the **CSS**

```css
.awningtop {
  position: absolute; left:400px; right:0 top:0; margin: 0;
  z-index:4;
  width:1000px;

 }

 .logotop {
  position:absolute; left:450px; top:120px;
  z-index:20;
 }

 .mainboxmid {
  position:absolute; left:380px; top:300px;
  width:1100px;
  height:900px;
  z-index:2;
 }

body {
  background: url(Pictures/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 margin-right:auto;
 margin-left:auto;
 width:960px;
}

 .headernav {
  background-image:url(Pictures/blue-gradient-header.jpg);
  z-index:19;
  position:absolute; top:270px; left:690px;
  width:639px;
  border-color:black;
  border-style:solid;
 }

 .headernav li {
  display:inline;
  padding-left:35px;
  position:relative; top:3px;
  z-index:20;
  font-size:1.2em;
  border:white;
 }

 a:hover { 
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  margin: 0; border-radius: 5px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  background-image:url(Pictures/BlueVectorBackground.jpg);
 }

 .headernav a {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:;
  border:white;
 }

 .bgbreak {
  height: 270px;
  width:830px;
  background: url(Pictures/bluechevy.png);
  background-color:#3366CC;
  border:black solid;
  position:absolute;left:500px; top:100px;
  background-size: cover;
 }


 ---------------
 $Thumbnails$
 ---------------

.polaroid {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:10;
}
 
.weddingthumbnail {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          z-index:10;
 position:absolute; left:600px; top:400px;    
 width:10%;     
}


.babyshowerthumbnail {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          z-index:10;
 position:absolute; left:900px; top:400px;    
 width:15%;     
}

.birthdaycakethumbnail {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          z-index:10;
 position:absolute; left:600px; top:750px;    
 width:15%;     
}

.holidaycakethumbnail {
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 45px solid #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
     -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px 3px #777;
          z-index:10;
 position:absolute;  top:680px;  left:950px; 
 width:15%;     
}

.babyshowertext {
  position: absolute; bottom:260px; left:590px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
  z-index:11;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.birthdaycaketext {
  position: absolute; left:297px; bottom:-87px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font: 400 18px/1 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  color: black;
  z-index:11;
}

.weddingcaketext {
position: absolute; bottom:220px; right:255px;
  width: 50%;
  font: 400 18px/1 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:11;
}

.holidaycaketext {
  position: absolute; left:640px; bottom:-190px;
  text-align:center;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font: 400 18px/1 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  color: black;
  z-index:11;
}
```

Here is the JFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/wm6r6rw5/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <header> is not correct. The right tag is <head>

Comment: <header> is one of the new tags from HTML 5, but it is for content, not for the head section of a document which usually references external style sheets, javascript, and contains meta information on the document such as encoding, viewport behaviour, title of the document etc.

Comment: Doh! Thanks guys, I seem to always get those 2 confused with each other. I am changing it in my code asap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic CSS is this:

```
.weddingcaketext {
    bottom:220px;
    right:255px;
}
```

Remove or sustitute them by left and top properties, example:

```
.weddingcaketext {
    left:220px;
    top:255px;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/wm6r6rw5/2/

Comment: Amazing! This fixed my issue along with removing the "text-align".  Also, if you notice in the jsfiddle, the spots where the pictures would be resize when the window size changes, any ideas on what could fix that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a HTML5 tag you can use that could help:

```
<wbr>
```

This basically tells the browser where an optimum place to put line breaks is, if necessary.

There is a lot more information about it here:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_wbr.asp